# Calculate difference of months and semi-month difference between two dates using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I want correct results even if month has 31 days or 30 days.

```js
var startDt = $("input[id=StartDate_" + i + "]").val();
var endDt = $("input[id=EndDate_" + i + "]").val();
var diff = new Date(Date.parse(endDt) - Date.parse(startDt));
var days = ((diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) + 1);

if (SelVal == "Monthly") {
  $("#div" + i).html(Math.ceil(days / 30));
}
if (SelVal == "Semi-monthly") {
  $("#div" + i).html(Math.ceil(days / 15));
}
```

I want to calculate difference where is Start Date is 10 April 2019 and End Date is 14 May 2019. I want monthly and semi-monthly. For this example:

- Number of months difference would be 1
- Semi-monthly difference would be 3 as mid of the month is
  counted by date 15 of every month.

For example the billing of any center takes place every 1st and 15th date of the month and I need number of billings between two dates.

Comment: You're going to need to give a much clearer description of what you want this calculation to do, and why it does not work for you as it stands. Right now there's not enough information here to help you effectively. A working example would also help.

Comment: Edit the question to include those details. Also be clear what you mean by 'semi-monthly' at that term by itself is meaningless.

Comment: Edited Please check

Comment: have you considered using something like [momentJS](http://momentjs.com) - it should make this kind of thing much simpler. e.g. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/ . Don't re-invent the wheel if you don't need to!

Comment: Please add more desired result use cases such as 29 march and 4 april, 1 april and 17 april, 14 march and 30 april, Feb 29 2016 and March 1 2016.

Comment: Please clarify as April 10 is before the 15th and May 16 is AFTER 15th so that to me would be 4 partial semi-months.  Please clarify how you calculate 3 here with that partial day sets as otherwise this does not have a clear definition. For now I am voting to close as unclear due to that.

Comment: For semi-monthly if Start Date is 1 April 2019 and End Date is 14 April 2019 answer should be 1 as we are calculating number of payments and each payment has to be made in advance. If Start Date is 1 April 2019 and End Date is 15 April 2019 answer should be 2 as the 2nd payment will be due for next half of the month. Similary if End Date is 31 April again number of payments due will be 2 as month has not ended.

Comment: So IF I summarize that comment up as: Any partial month or any partial half month counts as one additional value.  So then using my example April 10 to May 16 then is 4 partial month and 2 full month and your original question as 3 is wrong there for semi-month?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Thanks for correcting you got it right. Do you have a solution for my question?

Answer (score 0):

Okay try this:

```
var date1 = new Date("10/31/2019");
var date2 = new Date("12/1/2019");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
console.log(diffDays)
console.log("months: "+ (Math.floor(diffDays/30)));
console.log("days: "+ (diffDays%30));
```

have a look to the code snippet

```js
var date1 = new Date("10/31/2019");
var date2 = new Date("12/1/2019");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
console.log(diffDays)
console.log("months: "+ (Math.floor(diffDays/30)));
console.log("days: "+ (diffDays%30));
```

Comment: This gives days but the question is "months" and "semi-month" the latter based on 15th of month

Comment: @GUNJANASWANI, which case failed for you, can you please describe, I run the all test cases as you described in above question's comments